# Software to apply instagram like filters on Windows

Tags: windows, photography

I want a simple photo editing software for Windows, that will allow me to apply Instagram like filters - brightness, contrast, saturation, structure, highlights, etc.

I don't mind paying up to about $20 for the software.

Simplicity is key here.

Comment: GIMP has an useful command line interface, you can program then your own filters.